# Call aspx file from PHP page

Tags: c#, php, asp.net

I have a PHP file, TableUpdates.php, that I am trying to add a menu to. I have 2 different menus based on who is logged in. I have a MenuCheck.aspx file that determines who is logged in and then `include` the correct Menu.php file. However, I can not get this to work. Here's the relevant part of TableUpdates.php:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Table Updates</title>
    <link rel="StyleSheet" href="StyleSheet.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- #include file="MenuCheck.aspx"-->
```

I've also tried switching out the `<!-- #include file="MenuCheck.aspx"-->` with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<% if (User.Identity.Name == @"CORP\mmm976") {%>
<!-- #include file="AdminMenu.php"-->
<% } else if (User.Identity.Name == @"CORP\ibb601"){%>
<!-- #include file="AdminMenu.php"-->
<% } else { %>
<!-- #include file="Menu.php"-->
<% } %>
</script>
```

Neither works. The MenuCheck.aspx is this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<% if (User.Identity.Name == @"CORP\mmm976") {%>
<!-- #include file="AdminMenu.php"-->
<% } else if (User.Identity.Name == @"CORP\ibb601"){%>
<!-- #include file="AdminMenu.php"-->
<% } else { %>
<!-- #include file="Menu.php"-->
<% } %>
```

What am I doing wrong that this does not work?

Comment: This sounds like a very bad idea, what if someone opens `AdminMenu.php` directly? You need user validation in the language that will process the requests.

Comment: This is an intranet site. If someone found a way to open the `AdminMenu.php` directly they would only see links to more report pages. That's all this site hosts is reports. If the person looking isn't me then they don't see some of the ones that I've been using for testing, nothing really serious just simpler for the end user if they don't have to wonder what they are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have ended up creating a PHP work around. Since I'm trying to get the authenticated user and base the menu on that I had my server admin turn off anonymous authentication so that the php `$_SERVER['AUTH_USER']` would have the local user and not a blank. Then I added this to the php files in the body of the HTML for the menus:

```
    <?php  
        if ($_SERVER['AUTH_USER'] == 'CORP\mmm976'){
            include('AdminMenu.php');
        }elseif ($_SERVER['AUTH_USER'] == 'CORP\ibb601'){
            include('AdminMenu.php');
        }else {
            include('Menu.php');
        }
    ?>
```

I still have the `<!-- #include file="MenuCheck.aspx"-->` in the body of the aspx files.

So, although this doesn't actually call the aspx file and get the results in my php files, I still end up with the result that I wanted => the admins have access to the admin reports, everyone else has access to only the reports that they need.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to use two different languages in one script. You can make ASP script on ASP hosting and make API to authenticate your users from PHP script. Or just do from php:

```
file_get_contents('https://yourserver.com/asp-auth.php?login=xxx&pass=xxx');
```

ASP script must return you correct data you can work with.

You can't include PHP code to ASP script and can't include ASP code to PHP script.

But both your scripts may work at one hosting, just create web-server rules to correct handling .php and .asp.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused. So I should create an API to authenticate the users? Or does the `file_get_contents` work? How would I check the user against AD? The way I have it now the ASPX script is pulling the `User` from their windows login and then `include` the correct menu.

Comment: The `MenuCheck.aspx` should be returning the `include` statement. How could I use that? I tried adding  `<?php file_get_contents('http://engsys.corp.ftr.com/MenuCheck.aspx'); ?>`, but nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if the ASPX Page have methods like [WebMethod] on the code behind like this

```
[WebMethod]
public string getHello(string name)
{
    return "Hello " + name;
}
```